# Add to a list that is in a Loop using LISP

Tags: list, loops, lisp, common-lisp

I'm very new to Lisp and I'm having issues appending to a list in a loop. If my list is `missionaries` and I pass in a value of `cnt` (number of times to loop)  I need to take `M` plus current incremententor of the loop, concant and add it to the `missionary` list.  So as it loop I get `M1 M2 M3 M4` etc. .  Thing is, it just not append. I also tried `push` but then it runs on as `M1 M1 M1` never ending loop.

```lisp
(defparameter missionaries (list nil))
(setq x 1)
(setq cnt 20)
(loop
    (format t "~d ~%" (intern (format nil "~a~a" "M" x)))
    (append *missionaries* (intern (format nil "~a~a" "M" x)))
    ;(push (intern (format nil "~a~a" "M" x)) *missionaries*)
    (setq x (+ x 1))
    (when (> x cnt) (return x))
)
```

Comment: APPEND has no side-effects and in your code the result is not used anywhere. APPEND also expects lists as arguments, since you pass a symbol, this can never have worked...

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunatelly there is too many problems with your code - I have at lest 2 comments to every line of your code. I would suggest learning basics, some tutorials etc.

Comment: is Lisp this hard that all I want to do is run a Loop x Times and generate a value MX where X is increment  and add that value to list called missionaries.  I can do this in 4 lines of code in LIMS Basic and other lanag. LISP is so primal.  I know from my code above I have a List defined.  The loop works for the Format t.....  Now how do I add the value to a list.  Question is how

Comment: No, Lisp is not this hard.  But you do need to learn it, the same way you need to learn other programming languages, if you want to write vaguely coherent code.  [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) is one good place to start.

Comment: How do you do `(intern (format nil "M~a" x))` in LIMS Basic? Does it have a symbol type?

Comment: A good basic tutorial for Lisp is this book. Download a free version: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Answer (score 2):

```
(defparameter *missionaries*
              (loop for i from 1 to 20
                    collect (intern (format nil "M~a" i))))
```

Comment: Add comments, explain your answer, read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AksenP This code is basically an "executable comment"  thanks to the clarity of `loop`. The tricky `(intern ...)` part is cribbed from the question; if it requires explaining, it should be done there.